# How to query elastic search with Pair of value

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to query Elastic Search with the condition that the documents should contain the pair of values.

I have a pair of values, how can we query the elastic search with the pair.

Example:
This is the indexed data

```
{
  "messageId": "abc",
  "Identifiers": {
    "foo": "val1",
    "bar": "val2"
  },
  "labels": {
    "label1": "value1",
    "label2": "value2"
  }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the documents that matches the given pair of values.

For example if my pair is `pair(val1, val2)` then, when we query the ES with the `pair(val1, val2)` we should get the document with `messageId` "abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with Must clausule would be an option.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Identifiers.foo": {
              "query": "val1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Identifiers.bar": {
              "query": "val2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```